# replace value with prior value in a vector if prior value > value

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, lag

Im pretty new to R and cant solve the following problem:
In my dataframe df I need to replace values in a vector with the prior value in the same vector if they are lower then the values in the prior row. It need to be grouped by ID.

Example DF looks like this:

ID x
1 2
1 2
1 4
1 2
1 1
2 NA
2 4
2 2

and i want it to look like this:

ID x
1 2
1 2
1 4
1 4
1 4
2 NA
2 4
2 4

I have tried the following code:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(x= replace(x, x< lag(x), lag(x)))`
```

But i get this error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments.

How can i solve this (favouribly with `dplyr`)?

Comment: you can look at `?cummax`

Comment: actually this works well if i want to exclude the NAs. Didnt find out yet how i could do it with keeping the NA values but thats not too impartant anyway. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(x))  %>%
  mutate(x= if_else(x< lag(x), lag(x), x))
```

Hope that works for you!